# ResponseQueue: Can you send a queue as part of the message/body in RabbitMq?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

In MSMQ there is nice feature, called a response queue: as part of the message one can send a (private/invisible) queue as well, in which the reponse is awaited - very similar to the callbacks in the async world.  Technically this feature is just an wrapper around private queues and queue monikers.
Is there anything similar in RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured it out:

a private queue is created this way:

```
privateQ = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
```

and passing a response queue is via the reply_to prop for the send command (versus being a property of the message)

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='rpc_queue',
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                            reply_to = privateQ,
                            ),
                      body=request)
```

The real difference - actually hinted by the way the API is formalized - is that you should not create a reply queue for every message - as this is inefficient. The suggested way is to have one private queue to accept all responses, and to incorporate a correlation id.